# browse object array and delete objects

Tags: javascript

I have that array of objects that I want to be able to browse and leave in the object only those that comply with the array of permissions that are specified in the array of objects as data, including removing also the objects that are inside children

```
permissions= ["create:users", "read:profile", "read:roles", "read:users", "update:users", "write:messages"]  



[
          {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            icon: 'home-outline',
            link: '/',
            home: true,
            children: undefined,
          },
          {
            title: 'Profile',
            icon: 'lock-outline',
            link: '/profile',
            children: undefined,
          },
          {
            title: 'Users',
            icon: 'person-outline',
            link: '/users',
            data: ['read:user','create:user'],
            children: [
              {
                title: 'Users',
                link: '/users',
                data: 'read:user',
              },
              {
                title: 'Create User',
                link: '/edit-user',
                data: 'create:user',
              },

           ],
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.filter`?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't achieve the result

Comment: You need to be more clear about what exactly you need to "check for" in each object. I see only  one object  with "permissions" (expectedPermission)

Comment: Yes, I need to search the objects in the data of each one, that there is a permission in the array "permissions", if not there is to take it out of the array @i.brod

Comment: And what bout the objects that do not have a "data" property at all?..

Comment: Also, your "expectedPermissions" do not fit the format of the permissions array you have above..

Comment: @JorgeLuis is there a reason why the expectedPermission array and the permissions array use different formats (`read-user` vs. `read:users`)?

Comment: oh sorry, I'm correcting it is read:users @Subarachnid

Comment: I just corrected the code

Answer (score 1):

First, the values in `expectedPermission` array need to match those in the `permissions` array. If you don't control the values, you'll need to map them somehow. In your example, "create:users" and "create:user" won't match.

Assuming you resolve that, something like this should get you on the right track:

```
function hasExpectedPermissions(expectedPermissions) {
  return expectedPermissions.filter(function (expectedPermission) {
    // Only return expected permissions that are NOT found in the permissions array
    return permissions.indexOf(expectedPermission) === -1;
  }).length === 0; // If didn't find any MISSING permissions, we're good
}

var filteredPages = pages.filter(function (page) {
  return !page.data
    || hasExpectedPermissions(page.data);
});
```

If it's possible for child elements to be filtered, you'd need to write a recursive function. Something like:

```
function getAllowedPages(pages) {
  return pages.filter(function (page) {
    return !page.data
      || hasExpectedPermissions(page.data);
  }).map(page) {
    if (page.children) {
      page.children = getAllowedPages(page.children);
    }
    return page;
  });
}
```

Comment: I can't understand your answer, I just modified my question, I don't use expentedPermissions anymore, I pass you a direct array

Comment: Is there anything in particular that's confusing? Are you familiar with filter() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and map() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you'd like to remove from arrayofObjects.data any permissions not listed in the permissions list on top and delete the respective children too.
If this is the case, a solution could be the following.
It's a bit complicated but functional.
I hope that's useful for you.

```js
// ------
// Dataset 
// ------
var permissions= ["create:users", "read:profile", "read:roles", "read:users", "update:users", "write:messages"]; 

var arrayofObjects = [
  {
    title: 'Dashboard',
    icon: 'home-outline',
    link: '/',
    home: true,
    children: undefined,
  },
  {
    title: 'Profile',
    icon: 'lock-outline',
    link: '/profile',
    children: undefined,
  },
  {
    title: 'Users',
    icon: 'person-outline',
    link: '/users',
    data: ['read:user','create:user'],
    children: [
      {
        title: 'Users',
        link: '/users',
        data: 'read:user',
      },
      {
        title: 'Create User',
        link: '/edit-user',
        data: 'create:user',
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Users',
    icon: 'person-outline',
    link: '/users',
    data: ['create:role','create:user','create:test'],
    children: [
      {
        title: 'Create Role',
        link: '/edit-role',
        data: 'create:role',
      },
      {
        title: 'Create User',
        link: '/edit-user',
        data: 'create:user',
      },
      {
        title: 'Create Test',
        link: '/edit-test',
        data: 'create:test',
      }
    ]
  }
]

// ------
// Make permissions and object.data match
// ------
var elaboratedPermissions = [];
permissions.forEach(myTransformation);

function myTransformation(permission){
  let aux = [];
  aux = permission.split(":");
  if (aux[1].endsWith("s")){
    aux[1] = aux[1].slice(0,-1);
  }
  elaboratedPermissions.push(aux[0].concat(":", aux[1]));
}

// ------
// Filter objects
// ------
var arrayofObjects_Filtered = []; // filtered array of objects
arrayofObjects.forEach(filterObjects);

var unsupportedPermissionsIndex; // auxiliary array of unsupported permissions index 
var unsupportedChildrenIndex; // auxiliary array of unsupported permissions index
//separate variables/functions used for permission and children in case there is any mismatch or order difference)

// If object has no property data just return it else clean unsupported permissions
function filterObjects(object){
  var objectDataAux = object.data; // auxiliary var to hold object.data
  //var objectChildrenAux = object.children; // auxiliary var to hold object.children
  unsupportedPermissionsIndex = [];
  unsupportedChildrenIndex = [];
  if (object.hasOwnProperty('data')){
    object.data.forEach((givenPermission, index, givenPermissions) => {getUnsupportedPermissions(givenPermission, index, givenPermissions)});
    if (unsupportedPermissionsIndex.length > 0){
      // remove unsupported permissions from object.data
      object.data = object.data.filter((givenPermission, index, givenPermissions) => {
        if (!(unsupportedPermissionsIndex.includes(index))){
          return givenPermission;
        }
      });
      object.children.forEach((child, index, children) => {getUnsupportedChildren(child.data, index, children)});
      object.children = object.children.filter((child, index, children) => {
        if (!(unsupportedChildrenIndex.includes(index))){
          return child;
        }
      });
    }
  }
  arrayofObjects_Filtered.push(object);
  console.log("object: ", object);
}

// Get unsupported permissions (index)
function getUnsupportedPermissions(givenPermission, index, givenPermissions){
  if (!(elaboratedPermissions.includes(givenPermission))){
    unsupportedPermissionsIndex.push(index);
  }
}

// Get unsupported children (index)
function getUnsupportedChildren(child, index, children){
  if (!(elaboratedPermissions.includes(child))){
    unsupportedChildrenIndex.push(index);
  }
}

// ------
// See result in console
// ------
//console.log(arrayofObjects_Filtered);
```